# How to change settings of my app using Google Ads API so that refresh token doesn't expire?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-ads-api

I made a script using Google Ads API to get reports from Google Ads. But the refresh token expires every 7 days. I found out that it happens because the app should be published (have publishing status "In production" instead of "Testing"). So I did it.
But then the Verification status changed to "Needs verification".
[An option "Prepare for verification" appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnm8H.jpg)

If I try to "Prepare for verification" than it requires to authorize domain of my app.
[So this is an option for cases when someone wants to make an app for multiple users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCveV.jpg)

But it's not my case, I just get reports from my own Google Ads account.
I found out that probably the problem could be solved if I change User type of my app from "External" to "Internal". [But it seems that it only an option for Google Workspace users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARuah.jpg)

But as I see on their [site](https://workspace.google.com/) it is not free.

I am sure there should be some free option how to do this. Everything else works fine, the problem is just the refresh token expiration. Maybe I missed something, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, just set it to test and add yourself as a user.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did as you say. Will see if it works in a week.